# "Logical or" and "logical and" if statement in c different output despite looking the same

Tags: c

So I got this code sample I wrote. My goal was to print the numbers in the sentence that is stored in the ptr char variable. So the first part of the code does the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void preg(char *p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *ptr;
        ptr="John is 5 , jim is 2 and maria is 12";
        preg(ptr);

        return 0;
}


void preg(char *p)
{      
        while(*p!='\0')
        {
                if(*p>='0' && *p<='9')
                {
                        putch(*p);
                }
                *p++;
        }
}
```

But if I change the preg function into :

```
   void preg(char *p)
    {      
            while(*p!='\0')
            {
                    if(*p>='0' || *p<='9')// <--- Changed to logical or
                    {
                            putch(*p);
                    }
                    *p++;
            }
    }
```

The program prints the whole sentence ? It's seems strange to me cause in this case both logical operators seems suitable for the given task. I hope someone will explain me the difference. I suspect it has to do something with the way characters are represented as integers when they are compared with numbers.

Comment: Logical or `||` will evaluate to true even if one of the condition is false. This means that any character will be evaluated true as they are either higher than `'0'` or lower than `'9'`. Logical and `&&` will evaluate to true if both conditions are true. This means that only characters between `'0'` and `'9'` will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 5):

`*p>='0' || *p<='9'` is equivalent to true, since `'9' >= '0'`.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but do you basically mean that the statement is true always because every char as a number is ALWAYS greater than 0 ?

Comment: No, the expression evaluates to true for any set of integers. If `*p<'0'` the the second subexpression is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of the [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), it will help you to understand that behavior.

Actually, all the expressions of  `*p>='0' || *p<='9'` will not necessarily be evaluated. In the case of the logical OR, if the first expression `*p>=0` is true, the second one (`*p<=9`) will not be evaluated, because there's no need: the first one is true, then the condition is filled. It's an optimization to avoid unnecessarily expression evaluation.

So in your case, if `*p` is greater than 0, `*p<='9'` will never be evaluated, that's why you need to use the logical AND.